# Sql - I'm trying to count (Sum) a column where the value is between range of numbers

Tags: sql

So, I've been asked to find the # of times a value falls between -3.01 and 3.01.  I've tried count and sum..  Not having much luck.

```
SELECT     DateInserted, SetPoint, Actual, SetPoint - Actual AS Diff, SUM Diff BETWEEN -3.01 AND 3.01 AS InTolerance
FROM         dbo.TABLE1
WHERE     (DateInserted >= @Date)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Tag with the database you are using.  And explain what "not having much luck" means.  Using SQL is not (generally) a matter of luck.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using `SUM` with `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SetPoint - Actual BETWEEN -3.01 AND 3.01 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InTolerance
FROM dbo.TABLE1
WHERE DateInserted >= @Date
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt3H2.png)